# Performance issue in quarkus microservice

Tags: java, performance, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am having two microservices. The first one calls the second microservice via Vert.x client and the second microservice calls solr via Vert.x client. But there is a latency issue for all this process. The response comes up in 3-4 sec which is performance bottleneck. Is there any way or a tool in quarkus which can do performance analysis and give details of what all pieces of code causing performance issue ?

```
public class SolrWebClient {

@Inject
public Vertx vertx;

WebClient client;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    this.vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    this.client = WebClient.create(vertx, new WebClientOptions().setDefaultPort(443).setSsl(true).setVerifyHost(false).setTrustAll(true));
}

public Uni<JsonObject> search(URL url, SolrQuery query,Integer timeout) {
    int port = url.getPort();
    if (port == -1 && "https".equals(url.getProtocol())) {
        port = 443;
    }
    if (port == -1 && "http".equals(url.getProtocol())) {
        port = 80;
    }
    HttpRequest<Buffer> request = client.post(port, url.getHost(), url.getPath()).timeout(timeout);
    return request.sendJson(query).map(resp -> {
        return resp.bodyAsJsonObject();
    }).onFailure().recoverWithUni(f -> {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(new JsonObject().put("solrError", f.getMessage()));
    });

}
```

}

Before this in the first microservice we have a service which calls dynamodb for some for fetching some account records and then this microservice extract account number of user and search in solr via second microservice which is load balancing solr cluster. But I want to know what is causing this latency issue through some tool or some way if quarkus supports that..

Comment: If you have jaeger or a service mesh, you could use [OpenTracing](https://quarkus.io/guides/opentracing)

Comment: What does the code that calls the other microservice look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use Java Mission Control and Flight Recorder.

First download Mission Control from here https://github.com/openjdk/jmc (based on your preferred distribution) and launch it.

Then just start your Quarkus application locally (I assume you plan to check this in your local).

After that go to your Mission Control and see the list of Java applications there (your Quarkus app should be listed here by now).

You can monitor what's going on real live or you can also start the Flight Recorder.

Do load test (personally I like to use https://k6.io/), stop your flight recording and see the bottleneck.